# Scaling UV shells when stitching

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I have 2 UV Shells. (UV Shell A) and (UV Shell B)... (UV Shell B) is 200% the scale of (UV Shell A).

If I stitch them together they both retain their original size, but the edge where they are stitched is scaled to a size midway between the 2.

I there a way that when I select an edge on (UV Shell A) and try to stitch it to (UV Shell B) , but have (UV Shell B) scale to the size of (UV Shell A) so that there is no distortion in the UV Map?   I know other 3d apps have this option or do it by default... is there a way to achiever this in Blender without having to manually go in and scale the UV shells?

Note:..  (UV Shell A) has to remain where it is as it's already in the correct place, so I can't just map them again.

Comment: As I understand you want a smooth transition between the one island to another?

Comment: A screenshot of what you are talking about would be really helpful!

Comment: no. not a smooth transition. that's what I get already, i wan't it to scale the second uv shell to the same size as the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using Live Unwrap and pinning vertices of the islands.

First select one UV island and hit <kbd>V</kbd> button to pin all the vertices, then select and pin one vertex in the center of the second island.

[image]

Then remove UV seam in the place where the islands should connect.

Change the mode to Live Unwrap.

[image]

And grab the center pinned vertex of the island and move it until you have a desired result.

[image]

Comment: Here's an example: https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/9Dcbbc/

It's supposed to be a 1 button press and match the texel density / edge length exactly. This is how it works in other equivalent softwares. The answer above is kind, but not really the desired workflow.